# Series for envelope of triangle area bisectors

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, triangles, area

The lines which bisect the area of a triangle form an envelope as shown in this picture

[image]

It is not difficult to show that the ratio of the area of the red deltoid to the area of the triangle is $$\frac{3}{4} \log_e(2) - \frac{1}{2} \approx 0.01986.$$

But this is also $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(4n-1)(4n)(4n+1)}.$$

Is there any connection between the series and the deltoid? Or is it just a coincidence?

*([I asked this at MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110147/series-for-envelope-of-triangle-area-bisectors) almost 18 months ago and got no response)*

Comment: Uhm, "it's not difficult to show" .. I feel a bit embarrassed not being able to show anything. What's so easy about it? Can you give me a hint or a reference?

Comment: @Han de Bruijn:  You can use affine transformations to show the ratio is invariant.  Suppose the corners of the triangle are $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$ so the reflection of this diagram.  Then green area bisectors which do not cross the base are of the form $y=c+x(2(1-c)^2-1)$ for $0 \lt c \lt \frac12$ and the lower red envelope is of the form $y=1-x-\dfrac{1}{8x}$ between $(\frac14,\frac14)$ and $(\frac12,\frac14)$.  You can then find the area ratio by integration as $\displaystyle 6\left(\frac{7}{96}-\int_{1/4}^{1/2}\left(1-x-\dfrac{1}{8x}\right)dx\right).$

Comment: See the comment I just wrote to robjohn below his answer.

Answer (score 10):

Since $|\triangle BPQ|=\frac12\sin(B)|\overline{BP}||\overline{BQ}|$, to maintain $|\triangle BPQ|=\frac12|\triangle ABC|$, we need $|\overline{BP}||\overline{BQ}|=\tfrac12|\overline{BC}||\overline{BA}|$.

$\hspace{3.4cm}$[image]

In the diagram above, the endpoints of the lines are parametrized by
$$
P_t=\frac{1-t}2B+\frac{1+t}2C\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
Q_t=\frac{t}{1+t}B+\frac1{1+t}A\tag{2}
$$
for $t\in[0,1]$.

The points on each line are parametrized by
$$
R_t(s)=(1-s)P_t+sQ_t\tag{3}
$$
To find a point on the envelope of the family of lines parametrized by $t$ we need to find where
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}R_t(s)=\frac{1-s}2(C-B)+\frac{s}{(1+t)^2}(B-A)\tag{4}
$$
is parallel to
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial s}R_t(s)=\frac1{1+t}(A-B)+\frac{1+t}2(B-C)\tag{5}
$$
Setting the cross product to $0$, we get that
$$
\frac{1-s}{2(1+t)}-\frac{s}{2(1+t)}=0\tag{6}
$$
which happens when $s=\frac12$. That is, the locus of the envelope is the midpoints of the line segments
$$
M_t=B+\frac{1+t}4(C-B)+\frac1{2(1+t)}(A-B)\tag{7}
$$
$\hspace{3.4cm}$[image]

Subtracting the center of the triangle (and of the deltoid) at $M_\triangle=\frac13(A+B+C)$ yields
$$
M_t-M_\triangle=\left(\frac{1+t}4-\frac13\right)(C-B)+\left(\frac1{2(1+t)}-\frac13\right)(A-B)\tag{8}
$$
Thus, $3$ times the area of $\frac13$ of the deltoid is
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac32\int_0^1(M_t-M_\triangle)\times(M_t-M_\triangle)'\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=3|\triangle ABC|\int_0^1\left[\frac14\left(\frac1{2(1+t)}-\frac13\right)+\frac1{2(1+t)^2}\left(\frac{1+t}4-\frac13\right)\right]\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{3\log(2)-2}{4}|\triangle ABC|\tag{9}
\end{align}
$$
where $|\triangle ABC|=\frac12|(A-B)\times(C-B)|$.

Since the deltoid, as parametrized in $(7)$, is a convex combination of the vertices, it transforms with any affine linear transformation of the vertices. Thus, the ratio of areas does not depend on the particular location of the vertices.

---

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(4k-1)4k(4k+1)}
&=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{4k-1}-\frac1{2k}+\frac1{4k+1}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac12\left(\color{#C00000}{\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1{2k+1}-\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1{2k}}+\color{#00A000}{\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1{2k}}\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\color{#C00000}{\log(2)-1}+\color{#00A000}{\frac12\log(2)}\right)\\[3pt]
&=\frac{3\log(2)-2}{4}\tag{10}
\end{align}
$$

---

Thus, we have
$$
\begin{align}
&3\int_0^1\left[\frac14\left(\frac1{2(1+t)}-\frac13\right)+\frac1{2(1+t)^2}\left(\frac{1+t}4-\frac13\right)\right]\,\mathrm{d}t\\[6pt]
&=\frac{3\log(2)-2}{4}\\[6pt]
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(4k-1)4k(4k+1)}
\end{align}
$$
Perhaps there is another way to compute the area of the deltoid that makes it turn into the sum. However, it looks like a coincidence from this approach.

Comment: A pretty moving diagram, and I had not spotted the midpoint point before so +1, but sadly no direct connection between the two ways of reaching  $\frac{3}{4} \log_e(2) - \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: [+1] Very interesting. The fact that the three arcs of the deltoid are arcs of hyperbolas should provide another way to compute the area.