# Prove that in a triangle, there is a line which divides its area and perimeter into two equal parts, then the incenter is on this line.

Tags: geometry

> Prove that in triangle ABC, there is a line which divides its area and perimeter into two equal parts, then this line must pass through the incenter of the triangle.

Suppose line $L$ meets the conditions.
We have
$$Ac=Ab,\quad Bc=Ba, \quad Cb=Ca.$$

Also

$$\Delta AcI=\Delta AbI,\quad \Delta BcI=\Delta BaI,\quad  \Delta CaI=\Delta CbI.$$

But how is this helpful for proving incenter is on $L$? I don’t have any idea with this.

[image]

Comment: The converse property can be found there : http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/mp/previous2011/apr12sol.php with Haider's theorem giving a necessary and sufficient condition https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1086703

Comment: Area is OK. Perimeter is not split into two equal values.