Finding sum from the general term of sequence
I am given the $n$th term of sequence $$T_n = \frac{1}{(4n+1)(4n+2)(4n+3)}.$$ I am struggling in computing the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} T_n$.

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

See https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1708880p11011692

Try decomposition to some kind of fraction.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Not quite the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735794/series-for-envelope-of-triangle-area-bisectors as that was $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(4n-1)(4n)(4n+1)} = \frac{3}{4} \log_e(2) - \frac{1}{2}$

Does this answer your question? Calculating $\frac{1}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{5\cdot 6\cdot 7}+\frac{1}{9\cdot 10\cdot 11}+\cdots$

The answer is in https://oeis.org/A001505 : $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(4n+1)(4n+2)(4n+3)} = \frac14 \log 2$, and you need to subtract the term with $n=0$, which is 1/6.
